# How to make box-shadow using css as per given image as shown below

Tags: html, css

I want to create like that box-shadow design in my template:

[image]

Comment: where is your tried code?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-moz-box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
-ms-box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
box-shadow: 0px 7px 10px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
```